# Row header and column header for a particular cell in table

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to take corresponding row header and column header for a particular cell in table? I have table and I wanted to take the corresponding column header and row header of that cell when clicked.

Comment: Can you please provide your HTML as an example, and show us what you've tried that hasn't worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.index()`. To get the column use cell's index and to get the row, its row's index:

```
$('td').on('click', function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    var col = $(this).index();
});
```

The returned numbers are zero-based so row=0 is the first row and col=0 the first column. Add 1 to them if you want to start from 1.

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/90jckkyw/)